# Passing struct from C to Python with ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I'm trying to pass a `struct` from C to Python but I've problems when some attribute is a `char *`

test.h

```
typedef struct _FOO 
{
    int field1;
    char field2[5];
    int  whatever;
 } FOO, *PFOO;

 void CallPythonFunction(PFOO foo);
```

test.c

```
PyObject *module_name, *plugin, *PyTargetFunction, *ppresult, *pargs;
void CallPythonFunction(PFOO foo)
{
    // Set PYTHONPATH TO working directory
    setenv("PYTHONPATH",dir_python_modules,1);

    // Initialize the Python Interpreter
    Py_Initialize();
    module_name = PyString_FromString((char*)"test");

    // Load the module object
    if ((plugin = PyImport_Import(module_name)) == NULL) {
        PyErr_Print();
        printf("Error: PyImport_Import\n");
        return -1;
    }

    PyTargetFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(plugin, (char*)"some_function");
    pargs = PyTuple_Pack(1
        //, PyLong_FromUnsignedLong((unsigned int) validacion)
        , PyLong_FromVoidPtr(foo)
        );

    ppresult = PyObject_CallObject(PyTargetFunction, pargs);
}
```

test.py

```
import ctypes
POINTER = ctypes.POINTER

class _PyFoo(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('field1', ctypes.c_int),
        ('field2', ctypes.c_char_p),
        #('field2', POINTER(ctypes.c_char), # not work either
        ('whatever', ctypes.c_int)
        ]

def some_function(foo):
    foo_view = _PyFoo.from_address(foo)

    print("foo.field1: ", foo_view.field1)
    print("foo.field2: ", foo_view.field2.value)
    print("foo.whatever: ", foo_view.whatever)
    pass
```

main.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PFOO foo = malloc(sizeof(FOO));
    foo->field1 = 5;
    sprintf(foo->field2, "hello");
    foo->whatever = 3;
    CallPythonFunction(foo);

    return 0;
}
```

I need get this output:

```
('foo.field1: ', 5)
('foo.field2: ', 'hello')
('foo.whatever: ', 3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `test.py`, the type of `field2` is incorrect.  `ctypes.c_char * 5` is the correct ctypes syntax for a C `char[5]`.

Also in `test.py`, change `foo_view.field2.value` to `foo_view.field2` since it will not be a pointer.  Without that change, the Python code will throw an exception that isn't currently handled by the `test.c` code and it will just stop after the first `print`.

In `main.c`, `sprintf(foo->field2, "hello");` is going to have a buffer overflow because of the null terminator.

Comment: Changed like you said works perfectly. Thanks @mark-tolonen. About buffer overflow, yes, you are right. I translated my 'hola' for 'hello' to post it here.